# Application fragment crashes when launching it from history

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am getting following exception when trying to load application from `History`.

> Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0:
>   Error inflating class fragment Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: fragments.EventFragment did not
>   create a view.

App works fine when i launch it from `app icon.`

I have a base class and each activity extends from the base class. I am sharing the code structure,

**BaseActivity.class**

```
    public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        public abstract int getContentViewId();

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(getContentViewId());  //crash  happening on this line
            onCreateFromParent(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class HomeActivity extends BaseActivity{


    @Override
    public int getContentViewId() {
        return R.layout.activity_main;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreateFromParent(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    }
```

**layout.xml**

```
    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_main"
 />
```

**content_main**

```
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.fragments.EventFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

**Fragment**

```
public class EventFragment extends Fragment {

    public EventFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_event, container, false);
        HomeActivity activity= (HomeActivity) getActivity();
```

**EDIT**

**FRAGMENT_EVENT**

```
   //Constraint Layout

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        style="@style/AppTabLayout"
        app:tabTextAppearance="@style/AppTabTextAppearance"
        app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_selector"
        android:id="@+id/tablayout_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        ></android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tablayout_id">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Comment: Could you please share your fragment_event's layout code

Comment: Can you remove `HomeActivity activity = (HomeActivity) getActivity();` from the `onCreateView` method and put this in `onActvityCreated`

Comment: Not sure if this is the root cause, but I see that you are mixing `AppCompatActivity` with standard `Fragment`s, and this can cause some issues. You might try switching your `Fragment` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment` (in both `content_main` and `EventFragment` class).

Comment: @Mike: Updated answer

Comment: @PaulOkeke : tired you suggestion but still facing the same problem

Comment: @Bradford2000: *Event Fragment* is *v4.app.Fragment*

Comment: I'm specifically talking about `<fragment...` in `content_main`. That should be `<android.support.v4.app.Fragment...` I'm thinking.

Comment: @Bradford2000 - no, in XML, both use `<fragment>`

Comment: could you send `activity_main.xml` and complete code of your layouts not part of them because your exception is in inflation of layouts.

Comment: @BAHMAN, +1, I just put together a minimum sample project with the code above and am not seeing the same crashing issue. One thing that kindof stands out as a red flag to me is the `onCreateFromParent()` function. Why is this needed? Couldn't you just override `onCreate()` in `HomeActivity` and add your extra logic after calling `super.onCreate()`?

Comment: @Bradford2000: if there force upgrade or other flag available, then app does not launch main activity. In actual code, `onCreateFromParent()` is wrap inside `if./else` block. Can you please set background process to `No Background Process` from developer option, and try again.

Comment: @Kirmani88, same thing, cannot reproduce. I tried with both `No Background Processes` by itself, and also with `Do not keep activities`. Is there any way you can link to the code in Github (or provide a Github link to a sample project that has the same issue)?

Comment: @Bradford2000 sure, i will try to reproduce the same issue in sample project, and share with you.

Comment: get complete code of  method `onCreateView` from EventFragment do you return view from it always?

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code. Once fragment is created from layout you need to remove it before inflating it back

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id. fragment);
    if(fragment != null) {
        ft.remove(fragment);
        ft.commit();
    }
    setContentView(getContentViewId());  //crash  happening on this line
    onCreateFromParent(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: still facing the same crash